# Find the mass of a cone.

Tags: calculus

I am asked to find the mass of the cone. The cone has height 6, radius at the base 4 and the density function is $4+z$. I am asked to use cylindrical coordinates. 
For this I reason I should solve the triple integral $$\int_0^6 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^4  (4+z)rdrd\theta dz $$ But, I know that this cannot be correct because the radius of the cone varies. How can I describe the radius of the cone?

Comment: You can describe the radius as a function of height: It is a straight line with r(0) = 4 and r(6) = 0, where r(z) is the radius r at height z

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the vertex of the cone is taken as the origin and that the axis of the cone is the $z$-axis, the cone can be described as:

$$x^2+ y^2 \le \frac{R^2}{h^2} z^2$$

Where $R$ is the radius of the base and $h$ is its height.

Then, in cylindrical coords, $r^2 \le \frac{R^2}{h^2}z^2$. I.e. $0 \le r \le \frac{R}{h} z$.

So, $z$ runs from $0$ to $6$, $r$ from $0$ to $(R/h)z$ and $\theta$ from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the equation $$a^2z^2 = h^2x^2 + h^2y^2$$ where a is the radius at the base and h is the height, and then converted to cylindrical to obtain $ 0 \le r \le \frac{4}{9}z $ I do not think  I got the correct answer. The answer is supposed to be $176\pi$ but I suspect that is incorrect.

Comment: @Zeta10 that should be $\frac{4}{6} z$.

Comment: Right, that was a typo!

Answer (score 1):

Just use linear interpolation:
\begin{align}
r(z) &= r_{\lambda = 0} \, (1-\lambda) + r_{\lambda = 1} \, \lambda \quad\quad (\lambda \in [0, 1]) \\
&= 4 (1-\lambda) + 0 \lambda  \\
&= 4 (1 - z/6) + 0 (z/6) \\
&= 4 (1- z/6)
\end{align}